# How to start modal from button field in gridView from Code Behind?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am not able to generate modal from code behind using ScriptManager

I have already tried running the script  everything is working fine but problem is when I use  $('#myModal').modal('show') function.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/AdminPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminView.aspx.cs" Inherits="HotelReservation.Views.AdminView" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal() {
        alert("hi");
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

</script>
 <style>
    .hiddencol {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="table table-bordered" runat="server" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="HotelID">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"></AlternatingRowStyle>
        <Columns>

                    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="detail" 
                        ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-info" ButtonType="Button"
                        Text="Detail" HeaderText="Detailed View"  />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="HotelID" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="HotelName" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="Location" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="TotalDeluxe" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="PriceOfDeluxe" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="TotalSuperDeluxe" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="PriceOfSuperDeluxe" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="TotalSuite" />
                    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="hiddencol"  HeaderStyle-CssClass="hiddencol" DataField="PriceOfSuite" />
                </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenprimary"/>
 <div class="modal fade" runat="server" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Hotel CRUD</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="hotelprimary">HotelID: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="hotelprimary" readonly="readonly" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="hotelname">HotelName: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="hotelname" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="location">location: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="location" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="totalDeluxe">TotalDeluxe: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="totalDeluxe" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="PriceOfDeluxe">PriceOfDeluxe: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="PriceOfDeluxe" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                          <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server"   Text="Delete" CssClass="btn btn-warning" />

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add">Add Hotel</button>

<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal" runat="server" id="add" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Hotel CRUD</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <fieldset>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="HotelID1">HotelID: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="HotelID1" readonly="readonly" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="hotelname1">hotelname: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="hotelname1" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="location1">location: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="location1" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="totalDeluxe1">totalDeluxe: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="totalDeluxe1" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label" for="PriceOfDeluxe1">PriceOfDeluxe1: </label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="PriceOfDeluxe1" runat="server" type="text" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </fieldset>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="ADD" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />

                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

After that check my Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using HotelBAL;
using System.Data;
namespace HotelReservation.Views
{
    public partial class AdminView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = HotelBal.getAllHotelDetails();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("detail"))
            {

                int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                string hotelID = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
                DataTable ds= HotelBal.getAllHotelDetails();
                var query = from row in ds.AsEnumerable()
                            where row.Field<int>("HotelID")==(Convert.ToInt32(hotelID))
                            select row
                            ;
                foreach (var x in query)
                {
                    hotelprimary.Value = hotelID;
                    hotelname.Value =x[1].ToString();
                    location.Value = x[2].ToString();
                    totalDeluxe.Value = x[3].ToString();
                    PriceOfDeluxe.Value = x[4].ToString();
                }
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "step1confirm", "openModal();", true);
                //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "YourUniqueScriptKey",
                //"alert('This pops up');", true);


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to remove code unrelated to the question from example you've posted (see [MCVE] guidance). Also check out your browser's dev tools (F12) and see what is rendered on the page - it is always good idea to confirm that what you are looking for (element with "id=myModal") is actually present on the page as part of investigation.

Comment: Actually I  have found the solution I need set the clientid mode to static otherwise it was having problem with fetching the id